# How to create a Set in which only a single type can be added which doesn't permit subclasses or superclasses to be added?

Tags: java, types, set, type-safety

I want a Set which only holds one data type and doesn't permit any of its superclasses or subclasses from being added to the Set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `Object.getClass()` do determine the type of your objects.

if you want a guarantuee that only classes of a type MyClass are added you could just extend HashSet and override the `add(Object o)` method and only add the element to the collection `if (o.getClass() == MyClass.class)`:

**Update:** added a working example that you can run as PoC.

```
public class MySet extends HashSet<MySet.MyClass> {
    public static class MyClass {}

    public static class MySubClass extends MyClass {}

    @Override
    public boolean add(MyClass c) {
        if (c.getClass() != MyClass.class) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("illegal class to add " + c.getClass().getName());
        }
        return super.add(c);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MySet set = new MySet();
        set.add(new MyClass());   // works
        set.add(new MySubClass()); // throws Exception
    }

}
```

running this example yields:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   **illegal class to add MySet$MySubClass**

Comment: I don't think that would work as you cannot override `add()` and change the type of its parameters at the same time. Perhaps you meant `add(object e)` instead.

Comment: **this example works** you can add a main method and use `HashSet<String>` and `getClass()!=String.class`. i checked it.

Comment: @Peter:also the argument type of add() is the Generic Type E from `HashSet<E>` -> `add(E o)` so `HashSet<MyClass>` has `add(MyClass o)`: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add%28E%29

Comment: You are right, I was thinking about methods like `remove(Object)` and `contains(Object)`

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I think I misunderstood the point completely.

I would probably use composition rather than inheritance, delegating to a `HashSet<T>` internally, but in `add` you'd want to check:

```
if (o.getClass() != clazz)
{
     // throw or reject
}
```

Note that that means you'll need the actual class at execution time, so you'd need to construct the set with something like:

```
ExactTypeSet<String> x = new ExactTypeSet<String>(String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

In a very specialized case, where you know the type of the class that you want to add, you could you extend an existing Set implementation and override the `add(Object o)` method, only allowing objects to be added where `o.getClass().getName().equals("yourclassname")`.

Comment: Checking the actual Class would be simpler.  It is possible to have two classed in different class loaders with the same name. (I tend to find this confusing myself and avoid it ;)

Comment: You shouldn't compare the class names, but instead the class objects directly. There may well be several *different* classes with the same name at runtime (a name is only unique within the set of classes loaded by a single classloader, but there may be several classloaders).